# Is it possible to add custom setting in Resharper's Code Cleanup profile?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I want to convert all my public non-virtual methods to virtual. I'd like to do it in a by-project fashion (my solution has about 55 projects).

I'd like to add a setting in the Code Cleanup profile that does this for me. If you know any other way to do this I'd appreciate your help!

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with REGEX search and replace. REGEX:

```
public {~(<virtual>)~(<class>)~(<interface>)~(<enum>)~(<override>)~(<static>)~(<const>)~(<abstract>)~(<sealed>)~(<struct>):i}
```

Replace text:

```
public virtual \1
```

Comment: It'd still be nice to have ReSharper do it.  Hopefully some other folks will chime in.